# Is it undefined behavior to reinterpret_cast an object of an unrelated type to an empty class

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast

It it undefined behavior to cast an unrelated type to an empty base class?  And then use that address to construct a derived type that inherits from that empty base?  For example

```
class Derived : public EmptyBase {
public:
    template <typename T>
    Derived(T&& t) : EmptyBase{std::forward<T>(t)} {}
    using EmptyBase::print;
};
```

and then is it undefined to do something like this

```
static auto shim = 1;
auto derived = Derived{*reinterpret_cast<EmptyBase*>(&shim)};
derived.print();
```

The standard guarantees that empty bases must be optimized away in a standard layout struct, but not sure about whether something like this is allowed to construct a derived class

Comment: This code makes no sense at all to me. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't think that is an appropriate question to ask when I use the language-lawyer tag.  You should believe that the person asking the question needs such a thing in a niche situation that might possibly be hard to explain in a stack overflow post, especially given that they have demonstrated having tried to do research around the topic.  Moreover, several times explaining use-cases in detail with something like this becomes tangential to the post.  Which part does not make sense to you?

Comment: @Curious I meant what I said - I'm having a hard time understanding the code. If I can't understand it I can't answer it. Just a little context might go a long way.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> Derived{*reinterpret_cast<EmptyBase*>(&shim)}
> ```

`Derived`'s constructor accesses the value representation of its parameter to initialize its base class. The parameter has the type `EmptyBase&&`. But there is no `EmptyBase` object at that address; there is an `int` at that address.

Therefore, you are accessing the value representation of an `int` through a glvalue (`EmptyBase&&`) of a type unrelated to `int`. That violates strict aliasing.

So no, you can't just do that.

And no, it doesn't matter that `EmptyBase` has no subobjects. Copying an object accesses its value representation. Even if the derived class will overwrite anything it does (since the empty base class has no storage of its own).

Comment: And if the code was modified to (just to get OP's code to compile): https://i.imgur.com/IH2dwnt.png then the  parameter passed in isn't used..

Comment: @Brandon: Performing the cast is not where the problem happens. You get UB when you *use the result* of an illegal cast. If a bad cast falls in the woods and nobody is there to hear it, you don't get UB.

Comment: Does an empty base class that doesn't actually use the reference in its constructor still cause UB? That doesn't access the value representation?

Comment: Add `EmptyBase(EmptyBase&&){}` ctor and what happens?  I ask this because it fits the OP's title if not example.

Comment: My reading of the standard is that it is similar to the behavior of dereferencing a NULL pointer. That is, it's actually not clear if dereferencing it is enough or if you have to do something more in that location.

Comment: I think that has the type `EmptyBase&` and not `EmptyBase&&`, this is a strange situation.  What if that type is just union type and we use `std::launder` to access said storage as a reference?

Comment: Can you clarify why copying an empty object involves accessing it?

Comment: An implicitly-defined copy constructor of a union copies the object representation. An implicitly-defined copy constructor of a non-union class performs a memberwise copy.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341888/does-copying-an-empty-object-involve-accessing-it